# How to get data correctly from a django model to Django REST framework

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm working with Python 3.9 and Django 3.1.6. I have a quite long model in models.py. Short version is something like this:

```
class Check (models.Model):
    @property
    def total_body_fat_percentage(self):
        if self.client_gender == "M":
            total_body_fat_percentage = (self.Yuhasz * 0.097) + 3.64
            pass
        else:
            total_body_fat_percentage = total_body_fat_percentage = float((self.Yuhasz * 0.1429) + 4.56)
        return total_body_fat_percentage

    @property
    def muscle_weight_percentage(self):
        muscle_weight_percentage =self.muscle_weight*100/self.weight
        return muscle_weight_percentage
```

These fields return a float number. Something like 14.407.

Of course there are other fields in there such as Yuhasz, client_gender, etc.
I need these values into JSON. I tried to use the following serializer on serializer.py:

```
class PercentagesSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Check
        fields = ('total_body_fat_percentage', 'muscle_weight_percentage')
```

And I have the following class on views.py:

```
class PercentagesAPI(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    serializer = PercentagesSerializer
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        lista = Check.objects.all()
        print(lista)
        response = self.serializer(lista)
        print(response)
        json_response= json.dumps(response.data)
        print(json_response)
        data = {
            'percentages': json_response
        }
        
        return Response(response.data)
```

But it returns no data. Shell console states that it gets the queryset, it gets the fields, but it doesn't seems to get the values:

```
<QuerySet [<Check: Check object (1)>]>
PercentagesSerializer(<QuerySet [<Check: Check object (1)>]>):
    total_body_fat_percentage = ReadOnlyField()
    muscle_weight_percentage = ReadOnlyField()
{}
```

Thank you in advance for your advices and help!

Comment: You populate `data` variable but never use it.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'm sorry. I'm kind of an amateur. What do you mean by use it?

Comment: Is there a change that your intent was to return in response `{'percentages': json_response}`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'm actually following the structure from charts.js (wich will be the usage of this data). However `json_response` is an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You populate `data` variable but never use it. Instead you return `response.data`

```
 response = self.serializer(lista)
 data = {
            'percentages': json_response
        }
        
 return Response(response.data)
```

I reckon this is the solution:

```
 response = self.serializer(lista, many=True) # <-- many
 data = {
            'percentages': json_response
        }
        
 return Response(data) # <-- data
```

The query does return something - print shows 1 record/object: `Check object (1)`

Comment: It returns an empty array: 
`{
    "percentages": "{}"
}`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I spent all night figuring this out and now it's solved!